# If value exists in one PHP array, add value to second array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two PHP arrays. One contains a group name and another contains a pay wage value.

```
$group_wages_array = Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 4 [2] => 1 [3] => 3 );
```

This means there are four employees on the schedule. Two are assigned to group 1, another to group 4 and the last to group 3.

The second array is as follows:

```
$tot_wages_array = Array ( [0] => 500 [1] => 44 [2] => 80 [3] => 11.25 );
```

This is a sample array of each employee's wage. Both arrays are constructed in order as values are added in a mysql while loop as it pulls the info from the database.

---

Later on down the line, I combine the two arrays to get one array where the key is the group number and the value is the total wages for that group:

```
$combined_group_wages = array_combine($group_wages_array, $tot_wages_array);
```

This works like a charm EXCEPT for when more than one employee is assigned to the same group. These arrays are built in a mysql while loop as it loops through each employee's info:

```
array_push($tot_wages_array, $totemp_wages_sch); // Add their wage to the array
array_push($group_wages_array, $emp_data['group_id']); // Add their group to the array
```

Instead of just pushing the data to the array, I need to do this... I know the english but I don't know how to code it:

**If $emp_data['group_id'] exists as value in $group_wages_array, add nothing to this array but get the key. Add $totemp_wages_sch to $tot_wages_array where key = group_wages_array key**

I know it sounds more like an SQL query but I have to keep the keys and values in order so that they can be combined later in the page. If I can get this to work right, The arrays shown in the example would be:

```
$group_wages_array = Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 4 [2] => 3 );
$tot_wages_array = Array ( [0] => 580 [1] => 44 [2] => 11.25 );

$combined_group_wages = array_combine($group_wages_array, $tot_wages_array);

$combined_group_wages = Array ( [1] => 580 [4] => 44 [3] => 11.25 );
```

...I've got to make this work using PHP. Any ideas?

---

I came up with a solution based on a combination of two of the answers submitted below. Here it is if it can help someone:

```
        if(in_array($emp_data['group_id'], $group_wages_array)){
        $key = key($group_wages_array); 
        $tot_wages_array[$key] += $totemp_wages_sch;

        } else {

        array_push($group_wages_array, $emp_data['group_id']);      
        array_push($tot_wages_array, $totemp_wages_sch);
        }
```

Comment: In your last example code block, show your desired `$combined_group_wages` array.

Comment: Updated showing the new combined array.

Comment: I would suggest that you deal with objects, not these array abstractions.  I'll look over your code and try to help, but that's honestly what I would suggest to you.

Comment: @user971230: I mean show us your desired `$combined_group_wages` array when there is more than one employee in the same group. Show us what you wish the resulting array would look like in that case.

Comment: Whatever the best solution would be. I get a little lost in objects, that's why I'm using these arrays. Like I said, it works as long as all I need to do is "push" the data to the array and no groups are ever repeated.

Comment: @webbiedave: The last line is what I would want it to look like. Notice from the first example that group 1 is not repeated and the amounts 500 and 80 were added together. Now I would have a total wage for each individual group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This should do it:**

```
$group_wages_array = array(1, 4, 1, 3);
$tot_wages_array = array(500, 44, 80, 11.25);

$combined_group_wages = array();

for ($i=0; $i<count($group_wages_array); $i++) {
    $group = $group_wages_array[$i];
    if (array_key_exists($group_wages_array[$group], $combined_group_wages)) {
        $combined_group_wages[$group] += $tot_wages_array[$i];
    } else {
        $combined_group_wages[$group] = $tot_wages_array[$i];
    }

}

print_r($combined_group_wages);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 580
    [4] => 44
    [3] => 11.25
)
```

But I recommend that you just switch to using objects to better represent your data.

Comment: Man that looks nice but when I `print_r($combined_group_wages)` all I get is array()

Comment: @user971230 That is the exact code I ran my tests on.  You must have done something wrong when you copied or implemented it.

Comment: I came up with a solution based on a combination of your code and theprestig3's above. I'm posting it now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If I could see the entirety of the code that would help a lot, but here's your English converted to php. Show me more code and I can perfect it, until then try this ->

```
if(in_array($emp_data['group_id'], $group_wages_array)){
    $key = key($group_wages_array);
    $tot_wages_array[$key] = $totemp_wages_sch;
} else {
    array_push($group_wages_array, $emp_data['group_id']);
}
```

Comment: Yes I agree more info would help. Also at least half of it is an sql thing and a single (multidimensinal maybe) array could be built inside the while loop right away! Posting a table's description would help for this.